# Decision based on machine wanted

Tags: fonts

I want to use the roboto font for my document. It works nice when I compile it on my development machines. On our continous integration machine (running Jenkins) there is an old distribution of LaTeX on which I do not have influence on. Now I want to decide when to use the roboto package based upon which machine I build it. Can I do this in LaTeX or do I have to use Bash? I was thinking about using `hostname` for this.

Comment: I really don't see the use in having a conditional for a font based on two very different versions of a tex distribution.

Comment: Downloading of the font fails in the old version.

Comment: easiest and most readable way is to have `\usepackage{localfonts}` or some such then have `localfonts.sty` on your CI machines doing nothing or selecting a font they have, and `localfonts.sty` on your machine using whatever font you want

Comment: @EthanBolker: Thanks, I use `\IfFileExists{roboto.sty}
{
  \usepackage[sfdefault,light,condensed]{roboto}
}`
now. Works.

Comment: How about using the newer package (or fonts) in a local, personal directory?